# Negligence in saying something

Tags: idiom-requests, clauses

When I said something and I want to state that what I said was based on some level of negligence, what phrase should I use? For example:
There are two main parameters in the method: the number of retrieved results, k (we call k a parameter by negligence since it is in fact related to the evaluation measure used and is not directly a parameter of the method) and ...

What is the correct way of saying what I have said in the parentheses?

Comment: I don’t have anything to back this up (hence a comment), but maybe with a little rewriting, you could consider using  “out of convenience” and/or “for the sake of argument” in your parenthetical to acknowledge your "negligence" :... “(out of convenience [and/or for the sake of argument], we’re admittedly stretching/expanding the meaning of parameter to include “K”).”

Comment: "for lack of anything better" is another possible phrase